# Rails 3 how to do a query with a habtm association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I need to dump a set of Awards into a instance variable:

```
@corp = Award.find(:all, :conditions => ["award.category_id = ?", "2" ])
```

Award <= => AwardsCategories <= => Categories

I am trying to find All the Awards that have a Category of X

The interesting piece I am noticing is that my Award.category_id is nil but the AwardsCategory.category_id and award_id are both set.

The error is returning is:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in PagesController#award_cat

PGError: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "award"
LINE 1: SELECT "awards".* FROM "awards"  WHERE (award.category_id = ...
                                                ^
: SELECT "awards".* FROM "awards"  WHERE (award.category_id = '2')
```

Any ideas and merry christmas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a habm award doesn't need a `category_id` (after all, if it was used, how could an award have multiple categories?)

You need to join the award_categories table and put conditions on award_categories.category_id. Obviously if you have an actual category handy, you can just do

```
category.awards
```

Comment: I did join the tables... my mistake.  But even with modified query:       @corp = Award.find(:all, :conditions => ["awards_categories.category_id = ?", "2" ])
 I still get the same error with the names changed.

Comment: Nevermind... You were right.  I simply put the category into an instance variable and then call @cat.awards.all - Thanks and Merry christmas